# ASP.NET C# Select partial text from textbox pressing a button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, textbox, code-behind

I have a problem, I would like to be able to make a thing, with Code Behind (also with JavaScript will be okay) .
I have a textbox and a button and I would make this thing.

For example an user has written: Hello world, how are you?
Now, he highlight with cursor "how are" and he press the button that will put an extra text (for example: bla) before and after the highlighted text.
So, when the user press the button, on textbox he will have: Hello world, bla how are bla you?

Can someone help me? I thought that there was an option with System.windows.forms, but I have not found it.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

**Javascript**

```
function wraptext() {
    var SelectionStart = document.getElementById("text").selectionStart;
    var SelectionEnd = document.getElementById("text").selectionEnd;

    var OldVal = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var NewVal = OldVal.substring(0, SelectionStart) + " bla " + OldVal.substring(SelectionStart, SelectionEnd) + " bla " + OldVal.substring(SelectionEnd, OldVal.length);

    document.getElementById("text").value = NewVal;
}
```

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="123456" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btn" onclick="wraptext();" />
```

**Check demo here**
http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/P7gr8/

Comment: @Rashmin: Your code uses jquery. Can you simplify it to make it usable in plain javascript?

Comment: Edit done, logic was already in core javascript. i uses jquery to bind click handler only, but now all code in core javascript

Comment: @RashminJaviya: Thanks. I think this should help OP.

Comment: @DanieleNekoLuciani in jsfiddle link select 2 character from text and click button